# Accessing JQuery Datatable inside Angular 2 Component

Tags: jquery, angular, datatable

I am fetching data from an API and rendering it using Angular 2.

```
getData() {
        this.http.get('api/Employee').subscribe(result => {
            var localdata = result.json();
            for (var i = 0; i < localdata.length; i++)
                this.employeeList.push(localdata[i]);
            console.log(this.employeeList);   
            $('#example').DataTable();
        })
    }
```

Once I get the data I have to convert the normal table to Jquery Datatable using

```
$('#example').DataTable();
```

But I am facing below issue shows: **No data available in table** along with data.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally solved this issue by importing AfterViewInit

```
export class EmployeeComponent implements AfterViewInit {   

    ngAfterViewInit() {
            setTimeout(() => {
                $('#example').DataTable();
            }, 1000);

        }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest you to use [angular-datatables](http://l-lin.github.io/angular-datatables/archives/#!/gettingStarted)

If that is not the case you can use array source like indicates [here](https://datatables.net/examples/data_sources/js_array.html)

```
$('#example').DataTable( {data: this.EmployeeList });
```

Also remember to destroy any existing datatable if you have already created one

Comment: Thanks, but there are some limitations for using angular-datatables. and very less documentation.